# MongoDB Shell: Is it possible do an update query using a function?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with data like this:

```
[{
    _id: 1,
    address: '1/23 Fake Street'
},
{
    _id: 2,
    address: '5/20 Whatever Lane'
},
{
    _id: 3,
    address: '10 Foo Avenue'
}]
```

I'd like to perform a Mongo bulk update query, which does the following:

1. Transforms the `address` field to lowercase
2. Creates a new field, 'buildingAddress', which splits an address at the slash (if present, as with the first two items) and  uses the text after it to populate the new field

In Node, I'd do something like this:

```
  const cursor = db.items.find({});

  for await (const item of cursor) {
    try {
      await pageMapper(item);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

async function pageMapper(item){
   const newAddress = item.address.toLowerCase()
   const buildingAddress = newAddress.split('/ ')[1];

   return db.items.updateOne(item._id, {
      $set: { 
         address: newAddress, 
         buildingAddress
       }
   })
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in the MongoDB shell itself, passing in a function to `db.collection.update`? Or should I stick to the node driver for doing more complex update operations?

Comment: you can run js scripts in mongo shell
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#execute-a-javascript-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174720/executing-javascript-file-in-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2+, you can use aggregation or the pipeline form of update to accomplish that.

[$toLower](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/#exp._S_toLower) converts a string to lower case

[$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/#exp._S_split) to split the field

[$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/#exp._S_slice) or [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) to pick the element(s) to keep

One possible way to do that with update:

```
db.items.updateMany({},[
    {$addFields:{ 
      address:{$toLower:"$address"}
    }},
    {$addFields:{
        buildingAddress:{
            $arrayElemAt:[
                {$split:["$address","/"]},
                -1
            ]
        }
     }}
])
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Small error in the $split method though => this needs gto map to an array, like:

`{$split: ["$address","/"]},`

Comment: Good catch.  I totally typo'd that.